# Close mobile menu when selection is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have created a mobile menu for my single page website with the help from some code online. At the moment, the menu only opens/closes when you select the main navigation bar as a result of the javascript code I am using. Is it possible for the menu to close once a menu item has been selected so that when a menu item is selected, and the page scrolls to an anchor point, the navigation menu closes and doesn't stay open?

Here is an example of my current menu: https://jsfiddle.net/kmracozg/

HTML:

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>

<a id="touch-menu" class="mobile-menu" href="#"><div class="mobile-logo">LOGO HERE</div><div class="mobile-menu-dropdown">MENU</div></a>
<div class="header-logo">LOGO HERE</div>
    <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#"></i>HOME</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>ABOUT</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>SOLUTIONS</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>WORK</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>CONTACT</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i><b>CLIENT AREA</b></a>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```css
/* ---------- Google Font ---------- */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,700,800);

/* RESET STYLES */
*, html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, label, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td { margin:0; padding:0 }


body{background:#000;
font: 14px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width:100%;}




nav{display:block;
background:#ffffff;
text-align: right;
}

.menu{display:block;}

.menu li{display: inline-block;
position: relative;
z-index:100;}

.menu li:first-child{margin-left:0;}

.menu li a {font-weight:600;
text-decoration:none;
padding:40px 20px;
display:block;
color:#393939;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu li a:hover, .menu li:hover > a{color:#B11A25;
background:#e4e4e4;}

.menu ul {display: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
top: 43px;
left: 0px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.menu ul li {display:block;
float: none;
background:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.menu ul li a {font-size:12px;
font-weight:normal;
display:block;
color:#797979;
border-left:3px solid #ffffff;
background:#ffffff;}

.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover > a{
background:#f0f0f0;
border-left:3px solid #B11A25;
color:#797979;
}

.menu li:hover > ul{ display: block;}
.menu ul ul {left: 149px;
 top: 0px;
}

.mobile-menu{display:none;
width:100%;
padding:16px;
background:#ffffff;
color:#393939;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:600;
}
.mobile-menu:hover{background:#ffffff;
color:#393939;
text-decoration:none;
}

.mobile-menu img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

.mobile-menu-dropdown{ display: table; margin: 10px auto 0; }

.header-logo { position: absolute; padding: 30px; }

@media (max-width: 900px) {


.menu{display:none;}

.mobile-menu{display:block;}

nav{margin:0;
background:none;}

.menu li{display:block;
margin:0;}

.menu li a {background:#ffffff;
color:#797979;
border-top:1px solid #e0e0e0;
border-left:3px solid #ffffff;
padding:20px;
}

.menu li a:hover, .menu li:hover > a{
background:#e4e4e4;
color:#B11A25;
border-left:3px solid #B11A25;}

.menu ul {display:block;
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;}

.menu ul ul {left:0;}

.header-logo { display: none; }

.mobile-logo { text-align: center; }

nav { text-align: left !important; }
```

Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 var touch  = $('#touch-menu');
 var menu  = $('.menu');

 $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  menu.slideToggle();
 });
 
 $(window).resize(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  if(w > 900 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
   menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
 
});
```

Comment: `slideToggle()` menu again when the user clicks on links inside `menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the menu again, you must bind event to the `li a`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 var touch  = $('#touch-menu');
 var menu  = $('.menu');

 $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  menu.slideToggle();
 });
    $("ul.menu").find("li a").click(function() {
        if(menu.hasClass('mobile')) menu.slideToggle();
    });
 
 $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 900) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
            menu.removeClass('mobile');
        } else {
            menu.addClass('mobile');
        }
    });
     
  // initially to set the class name
     var w = $(window).width();
     if(w > 900) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
            menu.removeClass('mobile');
        } else {
            menu.addClass('mobile');
        }
    
});
```

```css
/* ---------- Google Font ---------- */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,700,800);

/* RESET STYLES */
*, html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, label, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td { margin:0; padding:0 }


body{background:#000;
font: 14px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width:100%;}




nav{display:block;
background:#ffffff;
text-align: right;
}

.menu{display:block;}

.menu li{display: inline-block;
position: relative;
z-index:100;}

.menu li:first-child{margin-left:0;}

.menu li a {font-weight:600;
text-decoration:none;
padding:40px 20px;
display:block;
color:#393939;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu li a:hover, .menu li:hover > a{color:#B11A25;
background:#e4e4e4;}

.menu ul {display: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
top: 43px;
left: 0px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.menu ul li {display:block;
float: none;
background:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.menu ul li a {font-size:12px;
font-weight:normal;
display:block;
color:#797979;
border-left:3px solid #ffffff;
background:#ffffff;}

.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover > a{
background:#f0f0f0;
border-left:3px solid #B11A25;
color:#797979;
}

.menu li:hover > ul{ display: block;}
.menu ul ul {left: 149px;
 top: 0px;
}

.mobile-menu{display:none;
width:100%;
padding:16px;
background:#ffffff;
color:#393939;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:600;
}
.mobile-menu:hover{background:#ffffff;
color:#393939;
text-decoration:none;
}

.mobile-menu img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

.mobile-menu-dropdown{ display: table; margin: 10px auto 0; }

.header-logo { position: absolute; padding: 30px; }

@media (max-width: 900px) {


.menu{display:none;}

.mobile-menu{display:block;}

nav{margin:0;
background:none;}

.menu li{display:block;
margin:0;}

.menu li a {background:#ffffff;
color:#797979;
border-top:1px solid #e0e0e0;
border-left:3px solid #ffffff;
padding:20px;
}

.menu li a:hover, .menu li:hover > a{
background:#e4e4e4;
color:#B11A25;
border-left:3px solid #B11A25;}

.menu ul {display:block;
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;}

.menu ul ul {left:0;}

.header-logo { display: none; }

.mobile-logo { text-align: center; }

nav { text-align: left !important; }
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>

<a id="touch-menu" class="mobile-menu" href="#"><div class="mobile-logo">LOGO HERE</div><div class="mobile-menu-dropdown">MENU</div></a>
<div class="header-logo">LOGO HERE</div>
    <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#"></i>HOME</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>ABOUT</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>SOLUTIONS</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>WORK</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i>CONTACT</a>
   <li><a href="#"></i><b>CLIENT AREA</b></a>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner to add a common class to each of the `a` within the menu, and bind the click callback to that.

Comment: Glad to help! please accept as answer if it has solved your problem :)

Comment: I am finding that when the screen is wider than 900px and the larger menu appears, when you click one of the menu items, the page scrolls to the anchor as intended, however the menu list slides up and disappears in the same way that the mobile menu disappears on click. How can i fix this?

Comment: When you're resizing add a class to mobile and add click event to that class instead of menu

Comment: Sorry, my javascript isnt the finest. I updated my javascript with your code, was there any other changes i needed to make? any chance you could update the jsfiddle link for me? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kmracozg/3/

I made a change in your jQuery. I added a click handler on the li element. To accomplish scrolling to the particular part of the page you will need to give each div or section an id and link to that particular id, like so:

```
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   ...
   <div id="contact">
   ...
   ...
   </div>
```

Let me know if you need more clarity!